# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 Network Interface Status Unclaimed

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, interface

I just installed the latest edition of Ubuntu server on a brand new PC I'm building, but I do not have a network connection. The motherboard is an MSI B560M PRO-E with an Intel i5-10400 CPU.

I ran the `lshw -C network` command and it shows the status as `UNCLAIMED` (see image below).

[image: lshw -C network command output]

I read in another post that my `yaml` file could be broken or I have a missing driver, but I'm not sure. This is all new to me, as I'm very new to Linux. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is a screenshot of the commands you requested. I was able to tether my Android phone for an internet connection (usb0) and run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. I ran both twice and rebooted. I also ran apt install net-tools and apt install dkms. The install is Server. Thanks guys!
[SecondScreenshotCmdOutputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk3c6.png)

Here is screenshot of sudo lshw -C network command.
[ThirdScreenshotCmdOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6QHw.jpg)

In continuing to work on this issue I ran two more commands; lspci -nn and lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net.
[FourthScreenshotCmdOutputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bSK.png)

Here is the output from the bios-version command.
[FifthScreenshotCmdOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bSK.png)

Here is the output from running lshw -C network command from booting to Ubuntu Desktop Live via USB.
[SixthScreenshotCmdOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0HpT.jpg)

Copy or move the file from the USB drive to /home/fluxnode/e1000e (still working on determining commands needed for this)

sudo tar zxf e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz

sudo cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/

sudo make install

sudo modprobe e1000e

sudo reboot

ip a (notate name of the device)

sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

network:
ethernets:
:
dhcp4: true
version: 2

Save with ctrl + X

sudo netplan apply

sudo reboot

The make command appears to be failing. Here is a list of the commands I ran up to this point.
[SeventhScreenshotCmdOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj7ND.png)

lsblk

mkdir /home/fluxnode/e1000e

udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1

cp /media/root/46F0-F603/e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz /home/fluxnode/e1000e/

cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/

sudo mv e1000e.ko e1000e.ko.HOLD

cd

exit

cd e1000e

sudo tar zxf e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz

cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/

sudo make

Screenshot from help.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDxJc.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135484/discussion-on-question-by-unclebot-ubuntu-server-20-04-2-network-interface-statu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brief install instructions:

**FIRST**, backup the current **e1000e.ko** kernel module to **e1000e.ko.HOLD**...

`cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/`

`sudo mv e1000e.ko e1000e.ko.HOLD`

Drag the downloaded file e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz from your USB to your Downloads folder.

`cd ~/Downloads`

`tar zxf e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz`

`cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/`

`make`

`sudo make install`

`sudo rmmod e1000e`

`sudo modprobe e1000e`

`sudo lshw -C network` and locate the ethernet **logical name**, then configure your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file with the desired configuration.

**Note**: examples from https://netplan.io/examples/. Change enp3s0 to the correct logical name.

To let the interface named ‘enp3s0’ get an address via DHCP, create a YAML file with the following:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            dhcp4: true
```

To instead set a static IP address, use the addresses key, which takes a list of (IPv4 or IPv6), addresses along with the subnet prefix length (e.g. /24). DNS information can be provided as well, and the gateway can be defined via a default route:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses:
                - 10.10.10.2/24
            nameservers:
                search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
                addresses: [10.10.10.1, 1.1.1.1]
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 10.10.10.1
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

The NVM for the on-board eth0 ethernet controller was corrupt.

Replaced the motherboard and it's all working now.